# D'Alembert and $u_{tt}-4u_{xx}=0$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I'm having trouble with this PDE

$$u_{tt}-4u_{xx}=0$$

$$u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0$$

$$u(0,t)=t$$

with $x\geq 0$, $t\in R$.

Making $w=u-t$ I get

$$w_{tt}-4w_{xx}=0$$

$$w(x,0)=0$$

$$w_t(x,0)=-1$$
$$w(0,t)=0$$

Applying d'Alembert's formula

$$w(x,t)=\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}g^*(s)ds=\frac{-2t}{4}$$

But this doesn't fit the contour conditions. What went wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that $w_t(x,0)=0$? Since $w_t(x,0)=u_t(x,0)-1$.

Comment: @LutzL My bad, thanks! I've edited the question.

Comment: @Shiele : are you sure of the conditions $\begin{cases} u_t(x,0)=0 \\ u(0,t)=t \end{cases}$ because $u(0,t)=t\quad\to\quad u_t(0,t)=1$ Then $\begin{cases} u_t(0,0)=0 \\ u_t(0,0)=1 \end{cases} \quad\to\quad 0=1$ : contradiction.